# Apache disable https redirect to renew certificate

Tags: http, ssl, redirect, https, apache2

I need to renew my letsencrypt certificate. For that, I need to disable the http to https redirect.
However I can't manage to to that.

I am running Apache und Raspbian. Here's my sites-available/000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin example@mail.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/tennis/public"

    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <Directory /var/www/html/tennis/public>
            Options All
            AllowOverride All
            Order Allow,Deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    #RewriteEngine on
    #RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} = my.domain.com
    #RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

I though commenting the last three lines out would solve the problem, however I still get an 301 redirect to https.

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

#Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) $1;Secure
Header always append X-Frame-Options DENY
#Header set Connection keep-alive

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I can reach the website via http if I use the IP address, so I know that http is still working.

So I can't figure out on which point I still got the redirect to https. When installing the certificate the first time, I used the certbot to always redirect to https, may be it sets this redirect somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is not a problem from my side at all. My dyndns provider got an issue with his certificates and therefore this error occurs.